# Unable to find UIView in UIStoryboard

Tags: xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard

I'm using Xamarin.iOS in Windows. Everything is working fine except:

Sometime ago, I'd create a UIScrollView named MyScrollView inside an UIView at MyViewController.

Right now, I can use it normally programatically like:

`MyScrollView.AddSubview(myButton);`

The problem is:

I can't find the ***MyScrollView*** at the Storyboard Designer. I want to change some properties at the designer.

---

### Question 1:

Is there a way to delete it and recreate since I can't find it at designer?

### Question 2:

Is there a way to use a *search* at the .storyboard file?

### EDIT:

1. Even if i right click over my UIView at the UIViewController, the Context menu doesn't shows the UIScrollView.

Comment: can you share your storyboard, view controller and view controller designer files? You can search in storyboard file, just open it as XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, It was created at the storyboard back-end, however it was just not showing at the Designer.

By adding the same component with the same name: MyControllerView it didn't duplicate, and assumed the original position.

Note: Special thanks to @Yuri S. It didn't solved by this answer, but i didn't know that i'm able to edit the storyboard via XML. So lesson learnt.